# Database select optimization, default row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a really quick lookup one row in a table which is not in the primary key. I have an idea.

My table will only have a few hundred rows, one column will be a boolean (not primary key), I want to run a select to see if any row has that column set to false.

When I update a row to set that column to false I was thinking I could also set a default row, so if any row is false then set default row to false and if no rows have false set default row to true.

Then when I do my select I only check the default row.

I think this would be a very fast select.  Does anyone think this is a bad idea or is there a better way to do this.

The thread doing the select needs to be really quick and the thread doing the update does not need to be so fast and I think can handle updating the row in question and the default row.

Comment: Are you using Postgresql or SQL Server (T-SQL)? Aside from that, it sounds like you just need an index.

Comment: @mrmannione . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually an index on a boolean column is not recommended.  However, for a query such as this:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from t where not column1) . . .
```

Then an index might be useful:

```
create index idx_t_column1 on t(column1);
```

You will have to test if the index is actually used on your database.  I would actually add a second column to the index, just to make it more useful, say for a `where` clause that had `column1` and another column.

That said, scanning a couple hundred rows is not particularly slow; so performance might be okay even when the index is not used.  If you are going to set a "default" value somewhere, I think it should be in another table.  However, wherever you set it, that has overhead -- essentially doubling the duration of `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you are often doing a query which is working on a non-PK column(s), you should create an index on this (these) columns, you will get better perfomances.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```

You can also verify this by doing Query Plan, the way to do this depends on your database type.